How to underclock RAM to reduce instability without preventing the system from booting?
After upgrading my BIOS from 2.6.0 to 2.8.0, my Dell Alienware R10 became unstable, with uptimes between about 0.5 and 20 hours. Downgrading the BIOS again, removing the CMOS battery, and Reinstalling Windows did not help.
The only option to under/overclock in my BIOS is for RAM. There have been reports of underclocking ram, so this may be enough. My RAM is Crucial 64GB Kit (32GBx2) DDR4-3200 UDIMM | CT2K32G4DFD832A. I don't see any Guidance on what my Tcl Trcdrd Trcdwr Trp and Tras my RAM supports, so I just left these as auto. I tried underclocking to 2650Mhz, but then my machine wouldn't boot, and my Alienware logo flashed white. When I rebooted again, my machine could boot, but my BIOS had reset my RAM to 3200MHZ. I tried underclocking further to 1050MHz, but this was even worse: the machine flashed Yellow and wouldn't even reset the frequency back to 3200MHz without me removing the CMOS battery.
There are many other questions on underclocking, but none of them seem to address underclocking preventing your computer from booting.
So my question is, are there some conservative values I could use to increase stability? (That wouldn't stop my computer from booting?)
I don't know if underclocking is the answer, but I have a Ryzen, so I doubt the recent Intel bug is my problem.


Yes; Underclocking can result in system instability.

@Ramhound That was not the question I originally asked. My intention is instead to reduce instability by underclocking. I have edited the question to resemble my original post more closely.

@gmatht, what is your PSU voltage in bios? is it stable? If your power is stable and you are sure this is issue of RAM, maybe try using MemTest86 to boot directly into test and check ram. As Ramhound mentioned, underclocking can be useful but ram must have "the range" otherwise its unstable as if overclocked.

Both times memory tests found no issues. Last time replacing the ram fixed the issue, but I have decided RAM is not the issue this time.

First, note that 3200MT and 3200MHz are different. 3200MT DDR4 supports only up to 1600MHz, so 2650MHz is actually massively overclocking the RAM. No wonder that didn't work.
If you set a manual frequency on the R10, it may not detect the correct CAS timings. So, if you set a manual frequency, also set the CAS timings manually. You can get your RAM's stats in a reasonably friendly format from a software tool such as Thaiphoon Burner; this may be easier than guessing which number is which on your manufacturer's CAS timing Datasheet.
Another approach is to overvolt slightly. Overvolting should increase the speed of the chip, effectively underclocking the chip if you keep the speed the same. Overvolting will not require setting any timings. Don't massively overvolt your chips; this can let out the "magic smoke" that keeps your RAM running. Corsair recommends not pushing the voltage over 1.4V. To be safe, I only overvolted from 1.2V to 1.25V.
If this doesn't work, a RAM chip may be defective. If you have two sticks of RAM, you can try using each in turn alone and see if this improves stability.
In my case, underclocking, overvolting and removing RAM sticks did not improve stability, so I concluded that RAM was not the issue this time.
